# end date > startdate date picker Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want the date picker to display the values greater than start date only. I have gone through many such examples but none explained why my code is not working. :-/

Here are my JS & HTML snippets:

```js
var start;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#s_dt').datepicker({
      startDate: new Date(),
      daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
      onSelect: function(date) {
        start = new Date(date);
      }
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(ev) {
      $('#s_dt').datepicker('hide');
    });
  $('#e_dt').datepicker({
      startDate: start,
      daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    })
    .on('changeDate', function(ev) {
      $('#e_dt').datepicker('hide');
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
  <label class=" col-sm-3" for="title">Start Date</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type='text' class="form-control startdate" id="s_dt" placeholder="Start Date" name="s_dt" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3" for="title">End Date</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <input type='text' class="form-control startdate" id="e_dt" placeholder="End Date" name="e_dt" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example below shows the end date as 1 day after the start date. You can make the end date by adding whatever number to `end` variable in `end.setDate(st.getDate()+1);`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var start = new Date();
        var end = new Date();

        $("#s_dt").datepicker({
            startDate: start,
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        })
        $("#s_dt").on('changeDate', function() {
            var st = new Date($("#s_dt").val());
            var end = new Date(st);
            end.setDate(st.getDate()+1);
            end.toLocaleDateString();

            $("#e_dt").datepicker({
                startDate: end,
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
            })

        })
          //basically this clears out the datepicker when you clear out the end date to select a new date. 
        $("#e_dt").on('changeDate',function(){
            $('#e_dt').datepicker("remove");
        })

    })
```

Comment: Hey, one issue with this. If I select some date for start date initially and then change the date again, the end-date date picker is not changing..( say firstly I selected 20th and then I have changed it to 25, the end-date date picker still shows the dates from 21st). How to solve this issue?

Comment: Just reset the whole datepicker for "#e_dt" so the whole thing is reset when you clear out the end date to select a start date.

Comment: You are right, there seem to be a bug that when changing the startdate, the date stays the same. This is due to the fact that startDate takes in a constant value. It doesn't take a variable so you can't actually change it dynamically. The only way to fix it is to play around with it and actually remove the datepicker itself when the user clears out the enddate or startdate to make a new selection. I have updated the top code to conform to this.

Comment: So you say I can't re-render the date picker of end-date when I change start-date? But, if you remove the date picker itself, then the user has to refresh the page to fill the form again. Is n't there any better solution?

Comment: I think you didn't understand what the issue is. If I initially select start-date as 20 and then end date as 22, and again I wish to change start-date from 20 to 15, the end date date-picker still shows the dates beginning with 20. I have tried to print the values of 'st' and 'end', both of them are getting updated when ever the start-date is changed. then why isn't startDate: of end-date date-picker not getting updated?

Comment: Yes I did.. what it is doing is, when I change the startdate after selecting it once,the end date tate-picker is completely disapppeared. Once I change the focus and click the end date field again, Its showing all the dates.. nothing is disabled..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var start;
$('#s_dt').datepicker({
    startDate: new Date(),
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    onSelect: function(date) {
        start = new Date(date);
        var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        var today = new Date().valueOf();
        if (selectedDate.valueOf() < today) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }
})

$('#e_dt').datepicker({
    setStartDate: new Date(),
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    onSelect: function(date) {
        start = new Date(date);
        var s_date = $('#s_dt').datepicker("getDate");
        var selectedDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
        if (selectedDate.valueOf() < s_date) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="form-group">
    <label class=" col-sm-3" for="title">Start Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type='text' class="form-control startdate" id="s_dt" placeholder="Start Date" name="s_dt" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3" for="title">End Date</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type='text' class="form-control startdate" id="e_dt" placeholder="End Date" name="e_dt" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Bind all condition on `onSelect` inbuilt option of date-picker.